# Iterate thru Excel column A , write to column B using Python win32

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I have an excel spreadsheet. I'd like to iterate through column A of that spreadsheet and write to column B using the value from column A in a string. I've been successful with copying & pasting in Excel using Python and have a couple scripts set up and now this one is presenting a hurtle. **EDIT:  I need it to stop once there are no more values in column A.**

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = 1;
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\file.xls");
ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

I've written what the code should look like below, but struggle with Python (beginner) and am not sure how to set it up:

```
starting read cell = A1
starting write cell = B1
for cell in column A:
    ws.Range("B1").Value = str("W"&TEXT(A1,"00000"))
```

So, if my excel spreadsheet looks like this:

```
A B
1
2
```

Then the result would be:

```
A B
1 W00001
2 W00002
```

(Notice I'm using excel formulas to write here).

Any suggestions?? Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
col = ws.Range("A1:A100")
for cell in col:
    cell.Offset(1,2).Value = "W0000%s" % cell.Value
```

Comment: This works wonderfully, Scholli. Only caveat (and I forgot to add this, see edit): I need to figure out how to get it to iterate through the column so it stops at the last value.

Comment: This is what I used: excel.Range("A1:A1").End(XlDirectionDown).Select() // last = excel.Selection.Address // col = ws.Range("$A$1:"str(last)) ..... all works beautifully, stopping at last filled cell in Column A. Thanks as always, @Schollii